# Implement Ackley function for Differential Evolution - using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, optimization, iteration

I have the following function for ackley

```
def ackley(x):
    a,b,c = 20.0, 0.2, 2*np.pi 
    f  = -a*np.exp(-b*np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2)))
    f -= np.exp(np.mean(np.cos(c*x)))
    f += a + np.exp(1)
    return f
fm27 = lambda x: ackley(x)
```

how can I adapt this function so that I can iterate through multiple parameter values
for example for

```
a = 20
b = np.linspace(0.6,0.9,7)
c = np.linspace(0,0.5,6)
```

and then print all results for each combination?
I have tried this so far but i still get only one result printed

```
def ackley(x):
    a = 20.0
    b = np.linspace(0.6,0.9,7)
    pii = np.linspace(0,0.5,6)
    c = 2*pii
    #20.0, 0.2, 2*np.pi #here pi has to be 0, 0.1, up to 0.5 , and b has to be 0.6, 0.65 , up to 0.9
    for i in pii:
        for j in b:
            f  = -a*np.exp(-j*np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2)))
            f -= np.exp(np.mean(np.cos(c*x)))
            f += a + np.exp(1)
            print(f)
            return f
fm27 = lambda x: ackley(x)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check the indentation is correct. I doubt `return f` should be in the loops (the same for the `print`).

Answer (score 0):

```
def ackley(x):
    a = 20.0
    b = np.linspace(0.6,0.9,7)
    pii = np.linspace(0,0.5,6)
    c = 2*pii
    #20.0, 0.2, 2*np.pi #here pi has to be 0, 0.1, up to 0.5 , and b has to be 0.6, 0.65 , up to 0.9
    for i in pii:
        for j in b:
            f  = -a*np.exp(-j*np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2)))
            f -= np.exp(np.mean(np.cos(c*x)))
            f += a + np.exp(1)
            print(f)
            yield f
print(list(ackley(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))))
```

This might help you